# Как в QMenu (pyqt5) передать параметр в метод?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как передать событию параметр? Через лямбда передаёт только параметр последней установки экшена

```
self.dayTasksMenu = QMenu("Текущие задания")
        task = {}
        task['1'] = "aaaa"
        task['2'] = "23123"
        for id, name in task.items():
            print(id, " ", name)
            self.dayTasksMenu.addAction(QIcon('exit.png'), name, lambda: self.selectTask(id))
```

В данном случае результат всегда "1" при любом выборе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В аргументах `lambda` напишите приравнивание `id`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dayTasksMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("Текущие задания")
        self.task = {}
        self.task['1'] = "aaaa"
        self.task['2'] = "23123"
        for id, name in self.task.items():
            print(id, " ", name)
            self.dayTasksMenu.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), name, lambda id=id: self.selectTask(id))
        self.setMenuWidget(self.dayTasksMenu)

    def selectTask(self, ud):
        print(self.task[ud])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```